# Operations on a triangle in C program

Tags: c, function

I am currently working on a C program that takes 3 (x,y) coordinates from the user (a triangle) stores the points in a 2D array and rotates the original points 90 degrees clockwise and stores those new points in a separate array.

To rotate a triangle you must:

1. Switch the sign of the x value
2. Swap the x and y coordinates

Example : Original point (8,5) would become (5,-8) etc.

Here's a snippet of what I tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
void clockwiseRotateTriangle(int oldtriangle[3][2], int newtriangle[3][2]);

int main (void)
{
    int triangle[3][2];
    int newtriangle[3][2];
//user inputs each point

    printf("Enter point #1 as x and y:\n");
    scanf("%d %d", &triangle[0][0],&triangle[0][1]);
    printf("Enter point #2 as x and y:\n ");
    scanf("%d %d",&triangle[1][0],&triangle[1][1]);
    printf("Enter point #3 as x and y:\n ");
    scanf("%d %d", &triangle[2][0],&triangle[2][1]);

    printf("Starting Triangle: (%d,%d),(%d,%d),(%d,%d)\n",
           triangle[0][0],triangle[0][1],
           triangle[1][0],triangle[1][1],
           triangle[2][0],triangle[2][1]);

    clockwiseRotateTriangle(triangle,newtriangle);
    printf("Rotated Triangle:(%d,%d),(%d,%d),(%d,%d)\n",
           newtriangle[0][0],newtriangle[0][1],
           newtriangle[1][0],newtriangle[1][1],
           newtriangle[2][0],newtriangle[2][1]);
}

void clockwiseRotateTriangle(int triangle[3][2], int newtriangle[3][2])
{
    triangle[0][0] = -1*newtriangle[0][1];
    triangle[0][1] = newtriangle[0][0];

    triangle[1][0] = -1*newtriangle[1][1];
    triangle[1][1] = newtriangle[1][0];

    triangle[2][0] = -1*newtriangle[2][1];
    triangle[2][1] = newtriangle[2][0];
}
```

The output doesn't agree with me though:

```
Enter point #1 as x and y:
2 7

Enter point #2 as x and y:
 -3 4

Enter point #3 as x and y:
 -1 0

Starting Triangle: (2,7),(-3,4),(-1,0)
Rotated Triangle:(1606416400,32767),(0,0),(0,0)
```

Can anyone explain why my rotated triangle is being so wonky?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main reason is that **you are assigning uninitialized values of** `newtriangle` **array** in your `clockwiseRotateTriangle` function

```
void clockwiseRotateTriangle(int triangle[3][2], int newtriangle[3][2])
{
    triangle[0][0] = -1*newtriangle[0][1];
    triangle[0][1] = newtriangle[0][0];

    triangle[1][0] = -1*newtriangle[1][1];
    triangle[1][1] = newtriangle[1][0];

    triangle[2][0] = -1*newtriangle[2][1];
    triangle[2][1] = newtriangle[2][0];
}
```

> here `newtriangle` array is uninitialized and so has garbage values
>   which are being assigned to triangle... that's the reason you end up
>   with random results

---

I think what you want is the other way around, i.e, using values of `triangle` array to get the values of `newtriangle` array in your `clockwiseRotateTriangle` function

```
void clockwiseRotateTriangle(int triangle[3][2], int newtriangle[3][2])
{
    newtriangle[0][0] = triangle[0][1];
    newtriangle[0][1] = -1*triangle[0][0];

    newtriangle[1][0] = triangle[1][1];
    newtriangle[1][1] = -1*triangle[1][0];

    newtriangle[2][0] = triangle[2][1];
    newtriangle[2][1] = -1*triangle[2][0];
}
```

---

After making the above changes to your code the output is as desired :)

```
Enter point #1 as x and y:
8 5
Enter point #2 as x and y:
8 5
Enter point #3 as x and y:
8 5
Starting Triangle: (8,5),(8,5),(8,5)
Rotated Triangle:(5,-8),(5,-8),(5,-8)
```

Comment: @CherubimAnand Ok, but if you switch the sign first and then swap shouldn't (3,5) become (5,-3) and not (-5,3) ?

Answer (score 1):

There might be other issues, but the main one seems to be that you are assigning to the wrong triangle variable inside the function, and then you are printing the uninitialized `newtriangle` array. Also, you were negating `y` and not `x`.

I think it should be like this:

```
void clockwiseRotateTriangle(int triangle[3][2], int newtriangle[3][2])
{
    newtriangle[0][0] = triangle[0][1];
    newtriangle[0][1] = -1*triangle[0][0];

    newtriangle[1][0] = triangle[1][1];
    newtriangle[1][1] = -1*triangle[1][0];

    newtriangle[2][0] = triangle[2][1];
    newtriangle[2][1] = -1*triangle[2][0];
}
```

Which gives the output:

```
Starting Triangle: (2,7),(-3,4),(-1,0)
Rotated Triangle:(7,-2),(4,3),(0,1)
```

Comment: You guys are all literally genius and I love everyone on this website. I can't believe I didn't think of that!